# http link not working correctly

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Attempting to use the hyperlink button does not work in certain circumstances.

[THIS IS MY HYPERLINK](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%E2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%E2%80%99t-part-1/)

The above text is actually a hyperlink, but does not appear as a hyperlink. It points to: http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-–-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don’t-part-1/

[THIS IS ALSO A HYPERLINK](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%E2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%E2%80%99t-part-1/)

The above is an attempt to use basic HTML to display the link:

`<a href="http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-–-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don’t-part-1/">THIS IS ALSO A HYPERLINK</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the URL parser here does not like the Unicode characters in the URL.

Percent encode the UTF-8 encoding of the fancy characters (U+2013 EN DASH and U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK):

```
http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/
```

Like
[this](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/), or
[this](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/), or even
[this](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/).

```
Like
[this][1], or
[this](http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/), or even
<a href="http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/">this</a>.

  [1]: http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory-sharing-%e2%80%93-vmware-has-it-and-the-others-don%e2%80%99t-part-1/
```

---

While playing with the URL I also found that you can just trim off a bit of the end and it will redirect to the full version:

```
http://www.cdhtalkstech.com/2008/11/03/memory
```

Comment: Nice find, but what a PITA.